# MySql query with multiple counts in result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a tables

```
create table posts (
   text varchar(20),
   created_at datetime,
   user_id integer
);

create table users (
   id integer,
   name varchar(20),
   important bolean
);

create table categories (
   id integer,
   name varchar(20),
);
create table categories_posts (
   category_id integer,
    post_id integer
);
```

Want to calculate the number of posts for each category between certain times with results like this

```
START_TIME_PERIOD, category, count_all, count_important, count_normal
'2013-03-06 23:40', 'dogs',    20,       5,               15
'2013-03-06 23:40', 'cats',    22,       6,               16
'2013-03-06 23:40', 'birds',   24,       7,               17
```

where the importance is based on the users importance.

To get one count e.g. important

```
select '2013-03-06 23:40', categories.name, count(*)
from posts, users, categories
where posts.id = categories_posts.post_id
and categories.id = categories_posts.category_id
and posts.user_id = users.id
and users.important = true
and posts.created_at BETWEEN '2013-03-06 23:40' AND  '2013-03-06 23:20'
group by 1, 2
```

What is the best way to get the three counts in a single result set?

Thanks

Comment: `SUM(IF(condition),1,0)` == pseudocount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ..... , count(*), SUM(IF(user.important,1,0)) as count_important, COUNT(*) - SUM(IF(user.important,1,0)) as count_normal
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using `COUNT`, you can use `SUM` combined with `CASE`, e.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN important = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count_important
```

Comment: Thanks - picked @Wrikken's as correct because it was slightly more terse.